# Git: How to point to one directory from few directories

Tags: git

I have the following directory structure:

- A -> B -> C
- A -> X -> C

A is the repository. X and B are projects (I actually have 5 not 2). C is a directory with a lots of code.
I do not want to place C in all projects and copy before each commit. I would like to be able to link all Cs to the same spot.
C has to be under each one of them because they are separate projects which are sent separately.

Is there a way to have only one C in GIT, but few in the directory structure? Maybe symbolic link?

Answer (score 1):

Use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), which allow you to link one git repository into others.

I do believe that it is possible to use a repository multiple times as a submodule in the same top-level repository, although I haven't tried it myself.

Submodules are superior to symlinks in this situation; even though git will recognize that files are duplicated and will only store one copy of each (even if you don't use symlinks), and even though the symlink will propagate changes to all of the repositories, git would still require you to individually commit changes in each of the symlinked files.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the answer.